# How to refresh only one jtable row on custom column value changed

Tags: jquery, ajax, grid, jtable, jquery-jtable

I have a jquery jtable that contains two custom columns. TestColumn1 displays numeric data based on valued that is in TestColumn2's input field. I need to recalculate TestColumn1 value everytime TestColumns2 value is updated. I only know that I can do it by calling jtable('load') and reloading entire table. is it possible to reload only one row ?

Here are definition of custom columns:

```
TestColumn1: {
    title: 'TestCol1',
    display: function (data) {
        return data.record.ProteinAmount * data.record.TestColumn2;
    }
},
TestColumn2: {
    title: 'TestCol2',
    display: function (data) {
        return '<input type="text" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think because there is no action to refresh one row only and _createJtParamsForLoading() does not support as well. This function should be desired for example is manipulating child table and master table contains a *total* field, e.g. invoice or so. But your are I'd employ Javascript assigned to input element.